# Trabalhar com Date no Mysql, JPA

Tags: java, jpa, data, jpql

Estou usando JPA e criando uma entidade para guardar um *date* dentro do banco de dados. Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que preciso exibir as informações do banco de acordo com o mês do meu `date`. Por acaso tem um modo de quando realizar o JPQL pedir para retornar apenas com o mês selecionado? Exemplo:

```
public void exemplo(Date data){     
    String jpql = "select t from time t where t.data.getmes() = cData"
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);

    query.setParameter("cData", data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro momento dá pra fazer uma alteração em na sua *query* para verificar apenas o mês, usando o método `MONTH`. Veja:

```
select t from time t where MONTH(t.data.getmes()) = cData
```

Depois bastaria resgatar o mês que está passando na sua variável `data` como parâmetro usando [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). Veja:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(data);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

query.setParameter("cData", month);
```

#### Resultado:

```
public void exemplo(Date data){     
    String jpql = "select t from time t where MONTH(t.data.getmes()) = cData"
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(data);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    query.setParameter("cData", month);
}
```